# Why is RegionIntersection failing on my custom Region?

Tags: regions, computational-geometry

I load a custom [region](https://ufile.io/jo8j6), specified as `BoundaryMeshRegion`

```
R = Import["C:\\data\\Profile.stl", "BoundaryMeshRegion"]
```

[image: region import]

and I try to find an intersection

```
intersection = RegionIntersection[R, InfiniteLine[RegionCentroid[R], {1, 0, 0}]]
RegionMeasure[intersection]
```

Where

[image: region bounds]

And I get errors:

[image: intersection errors]

Is this supposed to work ?  I can't figure out what I am doing wrong, here's all the troubleshooting I could think of:

[image: region troubleshooting]

I would really appreciate any tips on what I am doing wrong, this functionality works with standard regions like `Ball[]`, I would really like this to work on my region too!

Comment: Please try to upload `Profile.stl` somewhere; your question is unanswerable otherwise.

Comment: File added https://ufile.io/jo8j6 !

Comment: It seems like there's no intersection: Show[{R, DiscretizeRegion[InfiniteLine[RegionCentroid[R], {0, 0, 1}], 
   RegionBounds[R]]}]

Comment: Thank you @halmir for pointing that out!  I changed line direction to `{1,0,0}` to make sure they do cross, still same error though :(  Line direction `{0,1,0}` produces the same error again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a workaround, you could take boundary polygons and find intersection:

```
poly = Polygon[MeshPrimitives[R, 2][[All, 1]]];

line = InfiniteLine[RegionCentroid[R], {1, 0, 0}];

intersection = 
  RegionIntersection[poly, 
   InfiniteLine[RegionCentroid[R], {1, 0, 0}]];

RegionMeasure[Line @@ intersection]
```

> 33.6465

or to reduce computation time:

```
polys = MeshPrimitives[R, 2];

ipolys = Pick[polys, RegionDisjoint[line, #] & /@ polys, False];

intersection = RegionIntersection[line, Polygon@ipolys[[All, 1]]]
```

Comment: Thank you @halmir, this works!  I can use it as a workaround for now, after I figure out what it does :)